# Change the value of multiple items in a redux object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Say I have a redux slice with an initialState like this:

```
const initialState = {
   flags: {
      one: true,
      two: true,
      three: false;
   }
}
```

How can I change all those values at once? i.e if I wanted them all to be `false`.
To expand on that, say they were all a string and I wanted to change their value to a different string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some research/testing, I came up with the following solution for my particular case:

```
export const test = createSlice({ 
    name: 'test',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        flagSet: (state, { payload }) => { 
            for (var key of Object.keys(state.navFlags)) {
                state.flags[key] = false;
            }
        },
    }

});
```